# access header variable in cpp

Tags: c++, header-files

Hi I just started programming in C++ and have a problem accessing the variables from the header file in my cpp file.

In my header (Vector.h) I have

```
class Vector {

public:

    double x, y, z;
Vector cross(const Vector & v);
}
```

my cpp file (Vector.cpp)

```
#include "Vector.h"

Vector cross(const Vector & v){
    double x2 = y*v.z-z*v.y;
    double y2 = -x*v.z+z*v.x;
    double z2 = x*v.y-y*v.x;

    return Vector(x2, y2, z2);
}
```

This gives a `Symbol 'x' could not be resolved` error (same for y and z).
How to I tell the x,y,z are the variables from the header file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare your function in the class scope

```
Vector Vector::cross(const Vector & v){
       ^
}
```

This means that `cross` is a class method, and therefore has an implicit `this` to access the member variables `x`, `y`, and `z` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The error tries to tell you that there is no possibility to know what 'x' is and how to resolve it.

Your method needs to have a the class scope in your declaration:

```
Vector Vector::cross(const Vector & v) {

}
```

where `Vector::` declares the scope.